# Windows - ImageMagick v7 set text to 20% of parents width

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Using Windowns I would like to achive to set my copyright to my Images. This already works. But the problem is, that is always is differently big, relative to the image.

I use this command:

`script.cmd`

```
magick.exe convert IMAGE.jpg -quality 100 -pointsize 200x -background none -fill white -font Roboto label:"© Copyright" -trim -gravity center -gravity SouthEast -geometry +120+110 -composite IMAGE_COPYRIGHT.jpg
```

The problem is, that I alway want it to take up 15% of the parents width, so it is not to big on portrait pictures. On landscape it looks good, but 15% would be better anyway.

Is there a way to do this in batch/cmd on Windows?
I already tried `%[fx:w/6]` (about 16%), but that didn't work aswell.

Comment: I have not installed ImageMagick. There is the page [ImageMagick - Command-line Options](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) and reading this page carefully from top to bottom should give the solution. The page [ImageMagick Examples -- Text to Image Handling](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) is perhaps useful too.

Answer (score 1):

In place of adjusting pointsize, leave it off and set the width in -size "%[fx:0.15*w]x". Note the "x"

```
for %%x in (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.webp) DO magick.exe convert "%~dp0%%x" -quality 100 \( -size "%[fx:0.15*w]x" -background none -fill white -font Roboto label:"© Copyright" -trim -gravity center \) -gravity SouthEast -geometry +120+110 -composite "%~dp0copyright\%%x"
```

Comment: I tried that, aswell, but I receive the error `convert: invalid argument for option '-size': 0.15*w]x @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2855.` it somehow does not want these brackets.

Comment: Even if I use `-size "%%[fx:0.15*w]x"` (two `%`). I get the same error: `convert: invalid argument for option '-size': %[fx:0.15*w]x @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2855.`

Comment: Are you using Imagemagick 7 or 6. It won't work in 6. You need 7 and need to use magick not convert and not magick convert. `Just magick.exe!` Yes, in a Windows you need to double the % (i.e. escape them).

Comment: Lol you just repeated 1:1 my own solution after I posted it. I use ImageMagick v7 on Windows as written in the title.

Comment: So does that now work?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to not use `magic convert`, but just `magic`. In my case `magic.exe`. Otherwise it will run in ImageMagickv6 compatibility mode.

After this `-size "%%[fx:0.15*w]x"` will work. Please note the two `%`.

Thats @ALL for helping!